# How do you add pandas series filling each series' missing values separately

Tags: python, pandas

If I have two series:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s1 = pd.Series([1, np.nan, 2, np.nan])
s2 = pd.Series([1, 2, np.nan, np.nan])
```

I want to fill `s1`'s missing values with `0` and `s2`'s missing values with `1`.  But I want to preserve missing if both are missing.

I could:

```
s1.fillna(0).add(s2.fillna(1))
```

but this returns:

```
0    2.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    1.0
dtype: float64
```

And I want:

```
0    2.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just override your result if both are missing:

```
In [22]: s1.fillna(0).add(s2.fillna(1)).where(~s1.isnull() | ~s2.isnull(), np.nan)
Out[22]:
0     2
1     2
2     3
3   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could:

```
df = pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)
df[~df.isnull().all(axis=1)].fillna({c: c for c in df.columns}).append(df[df.isnull().all(axis=1)]).sum(axis=1)
```

to get:

```
0    2.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    NaN
```